# Apache cxf Marshalling error : class ** nor any of it s super class is known to this context

Tags: java, apache, web-services, jaxb, cxf

I am writing a client using apache cxf for an existing OLD web service.
In the wsdl there is a complex section like

```
<xs:complexType name="payloadType" mixed="true">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:any namespace="##any" processContents="lax" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="ID" type="xs:ID" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="filename" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

And I am passing a jaxb bean in an array as *payloadType* . The payload type definition is something like this

```
<xs:complexType name="abc.xyz">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="code" type="CV" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
....
</xs:complexType>
```

And the generated Java class is something like this

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "abc.xyz", propOrder = {
    "code",
   ...
})
public class xyz {
...
}
```

The apache cxf endpoint is throwing exception while marshalling.

Following is the log.

> org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Marshalling Error: class
>   somepackage.abcxyz nor
>   any of its super class is known to this context.  at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.marshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:266)
>   ~[cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]    at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataWriterImpl.write(DataWriterImpl.java:225)
>   ~[cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]    at
>   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.writeParts(AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.java:121)
>   ~[cxf-core-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]   at
>   org.apache.cxf.wsdl.interceptors.BareOutInterceptor.handleMessage(BareOutInterceptor.java:69)
>   ~[cxf-rt-wsdl-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]    at
>   org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
>   ~[cxf-core-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]   at
>   org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:514)
>   [cxf-core-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]    at
>   org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:416)
>   [cxf-core-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]    at
>   org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfProducer.process(CxfProducer.java:112)
>   [camel-cxf-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]     at
>   uk.co.corelogic.mis.core.component.cxf.MisCxfProducer.process(MisCxfProducer.java:45)
>   [core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:120)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:163)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:416)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:51)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:416)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessSequential(MulticastProcessor.java:586)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessSequential(MulticastProcessor.java:514)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.process(MulticastProcessor.java:226)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.RecipientList.sendToRecipientList(RecipientList.java:167)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.RecipientList.process(RecipientList.java:120)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:163)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:416)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:51)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:120)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:163)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:416)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:51)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:120)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:163)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:416)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.ChoiceProcessor.process(ChoiceProcessor.java:111)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:163)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:416)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:51)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:120)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:163)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:416)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:416)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:105)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessParallel(MulticastProcessor.java:732)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.access$200(MulticastProcessor.java:82)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$1.call(MulticastProcessor.java:303)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$1.call(MulticastProcessor.java:288)
>   [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>   [na:1.6.0_37]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) [na:1.6.0_37]
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>   [na:1.6.0_37]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>   [na:1.6.0_37]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [na:1.6.0_37]
>   Caused by: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException: null  at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:326)
>   ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]  at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:251)
>   ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]  at
>   javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:75)
>   ~[na:1.6.0_37]    at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.writeObject(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:613)
>   ~[cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]    at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.marshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:241)
>   ~[cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]    ... 74 common frames
>   omitted Caused by: com.sun.istack.SAXException2: class
>   org.hl7.v3.COMTMT000007UK02AssessmentNotificationAcceptResponse nor
>   any of its super class is known to this context.  at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(XMLSerializer.java:247)
>   ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]  at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(XMLSerializer.java:262)
>   ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]  at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayReferenceNodeProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayReferenceNodeProperty.java:122)
>   ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]  at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:159)
>   ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]  at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:361)
>   ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]  at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
>   ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]  at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.serializeItem(ArrayElementNodeProperty.java:69)
>   ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]  at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayElementProperty.java:172)
>   ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]  at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:159)
>   ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]  at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:361)
>   ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]  at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
>   ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]  at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:158)
>   ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]  at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:361)
>   ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]  at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
>   ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]  at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:158)
>   ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]  at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:161)
>   ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]  at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:131)
>   ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]  at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:333)
>   ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]  at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:340)
>   ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]  at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:76)
>   ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]  at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:494)
>   ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]  at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:323)
>   ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]  ... 78 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class
>   org.hl7.v3.COMTMT000007UK02AssessmentNotificationAcceptResponse nor
>   any of its super class is known to this context.  at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getBeanInfo(JAXBContextImpl.java:593)
>   ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]  at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayReferenceNodeProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayReferenceNodeProperty.java:112)
>   ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]  ... 97 common frames omitted

I noticed that my complex type is abc**.**xyz and generated java class named xyz with @xmltype(name =abc.xyz) and the wsdl file pointed client is correct.